# Does javascript have specificity?

Tags: html, css

I gave a div in my html file, a height of 100x and a width of 100px. I was trying to output the height using javascript, like this..

`console.log(document.GetElementById("box").style.height);`
 // i gave the div an ID of box and styled it using css,but it console.logged an empty line.

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVqEg.png


//But when i styled the div using **css inline styling**,it console.logged the height.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/biXZK.png

Comment: well that should be an error since it is not `GetElementById` It would help if you showed the html in the post of what worked, not an image of a console line.

Comment: You really need to post the code yu are having troubles with, and be more specific on what issue you are having.

Comment: [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: @epascarello doesn't `getBoundintClientRect` return more information about the position of the element in the viewport? OP, `getElementById()` is the correct usage (no capital Get), but you need to post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: An element’s `.style` property gives you the attributes of its `style="..."` attribute, not its computed style.

Comment: @disinfor why does it matter if it gives more than the height?

Comment: @epascarello it doesn't matter...I was more curious.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the value of the `style` attribute, you need to get the computed height of your `#box` element.

There are a few ways to do this.

```js
// includes height + vertical padding
var h = document.getElementById('box').clientHeight;

// includes height + top/bottom padding + top/bottom borders
var h = document.getElementById('box').offsetHeight;

// includes height of the contained document
// (possibly larger than mere height in case of overflow scrolling)
// + top/bottom padding + top/bottom borders
var h = document.getElementById('box').scrollHeight;
```

Also be sure you're calling `getElementById()` with a lowercase `g` at the beginning.